# Is anybody else bothered by the phrase "in the meanwhile?"

Tags: word-usage

The way I understand the usage, it's  "in the mean**time**," (phrase) and  "mean**while**," (single word) and they are not exactly equivalent in meaning.

Then about 10 years ago, I started seeing "in the mean**while**" in published books, which makes me cringe like fingernails on a blackboard.

Comment: I'm bothered by it, but I find @deadrat's answer compelling. I'm no longer as bothered.

Comment: I did wonder at some point, but I remember checking (not sure _which_ dictionary) and finding that it is accepted usage.

Comment: I would never use *in the meanwhile*. I find it bothersome. It should be just *meanwhile,...* This is my own opinion, regardless and irregardless of what others do.

Answer (score 5):

*Meanwhile* (originally two words, *mean while*) combines *mean* (intermediate) and *while* (time period) to describe some interval between two events. It has two uses. The first is adverbial, equivalent to "during the interval defined", and it's this meaning that grates on you since the preposition *in* seems superfluous to requirements with the built-in meaning of *during*.

But per the OED, *meanwhile* is also a noun, defined as that intermediate interval. And it has been since the word entered the written language in the 1370s. As a noun, it has a natural home as the object of the preposition *in*.

The Ngram viewer finds the usage *in the meanwhile* in books published in 1800 and those published in 2000. In the meanwhile, the usage has been acceptable.

So you can stop cringing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying nicely and I especially like the *pun*chline.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, though, that [_in the meantime_ is by far the more common of the two](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+meantime%2Cin+the+meanwhile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) and has been since the dawn of Ngram time.

Comment: Funny that _meantime_ cannot be used adverbially though.